# What does the neuralnet error reported in plot mean?

Tags: r, neural-networks

When fitting a simple MLP neural net on the *Credit* dataset by the package `neuralnet` in R and then plotting it, we get an error reported at the bottom of the plot, as here:

```
library(ISLR2)
library(neuralnet)
data(Credit)
set.seed(1)
nn <- neuralnet(Balance ~ Income + Limit + Rating + Cards + Age + Education, data = Credit, linear.output = TRUE)
plot(nn, rep = "best")
```

How is the error 0.67 computed? The function's help doesn't help indeed, as the error here reported is much smaller than an SSE (RSS). Thanks.

Comment: Can it be mean squared error?